# How to get response from firebase function into my webpage and print as console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Here I want to put the mathematical formula in my firebase function as a backend code and respond the result to the client into my website when HTTP trigged. But I dun know how to respond the result to the client when it was triggered. And also we can't respond directly using .send() function as javascript use promise to check.
[image: This response from firebase when we call HTTP directly from browser]
[image: This is my backend firebase function code]

Comment: Your question is not quite clear.

Comment: in simply, I want to fetch the result to the client webpage

Comment: yes so just use response.send(result) from cloud function and display it on your browser. You will have to call the API from the client application!

Comment: I want to show up in the HTML element. Cloud you tell me more details using about API call in the client application as I'm really new to firebase function

Comment: in which framework you are building your client side?

Comment: i do not use any framework. and my page is simple web page just using javascript

Comment: ok so use jquery to make an API call.

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: "//www.site.com/resource"
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data) {
                $(".demo-card").html(data);
            }
    });

Comment: I got error in the developer tools.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-*****.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Please add you client code as well here

Comment: Add this line your function:  response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")

Comment: finally, i got it. thank you very much. I search the these error almost 2days

Comment: @SunnyParekh Thanks for the help. Can you post your comments to the answer section so that we may upvote it?

Comment: @JKleinne, done. Do the needful

Answer (score 1):

Try to call your API using AJAX (jQuery) as mentioned below:

```
 $.ajax(
{ url: "//www.site.com/resource" 
dataType: "jsonp", 
success: function(data) 
{ $(".demo-card").html(data); }
});
```

Also, make sure to handle CORS in your cloud function:

```
response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
```